# jQuery tablesorterPager displaying record information summary

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, jquery-pagination

Does anyone know how to have tablesorter pager plugin display the following infromation:

Displaying 1 to 10 of 57 records

That's just an example but I cant figure out where i can get the first two numbers based on how many records i am displaying per page.. I figured out how to get the total # of records. Not sure if there's a way i can get the other two numbers based off of that or not.. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I've recently added a fork of the [tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/) plugin on github with some improvements and missing documents. After seeing this request, I've also updated the pager plugin to allow you to create a custom output. To get the output you requested, use this code ([demo](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-pager.html)):

```
$("table")
  // initialize tablesorter
  .tablesorter()

  // initialize the pager plugin
  .tablesorterPager({
    // target the pager markup
    container: $("#pager"),
    // output default: '{page}/{totalPages}'
    output: 'Displaying {startRow} to {endRow} of {totalRows} records'
  });
```

Also, the original pager HTML markup displayed this inside an input. You can now use any element. See the demo page for a full example.

Comment: That's awesome! thanks for the update! i'll be sure to check it out